# Absolute minimum from $[0,\infty)$ of a function $f(x) = 0$ for $x=0$ and $f(x)=\frac1x$ otherwise.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find the absolute minimum of a function defined like this:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,&&x=0\\
\frac1x,&&otherwise
\end{cases}
$$
On the interval $[0,\infty)$.

It seems obvious that the absolute minimum is 0, but I can't find it by taking the derivative. If I take the derivative, the result is $\frac{-1}{x^2}$, which is never equal to 0. This implies that there are no critical points.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Any help is much appreciated,
thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

We know $\frac{1}{x} > 0$ whenever $x > 0$ (Depending on how strict your teacher grades, you could perhaps provide one or two sentences of justification). So the absolute minimum must be at $x = 0$, which is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You always want to test your endpoints, as well as any critical points. Take for example, the function $y=x$ on the interval $[1,2]$. This function has no critical points, but it clearly has a global min at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is the Closed Interval Method, which states that any maximums or minimums of a function on a closed interval appear either at a critical point or at the beginning or end of the function. However, to answer your question, I will assume something:

I will assume that when you said $[0,\infty]$ you meant $[0, \infty)$, in which case we need to find the limit of the minimum of $f$ on the interval $[0,t]$ as t goes to infinity. However, we must note that if we find the limit of $t$ as $t$ goes to $\infty$ to be the absolute minimum, we have no minimum as $1/x$ never actually attains its minimum value on $(0,\infty)$

From this point of view, we have a critical point at $x=0$, and the boundaries at $x=0$ and $x=t$ as $t$ goes to infinity, and these are all the points we must check.

Therefore, we can find the absolute minimum of $f$ by finding which of the following is the smallest:

$$f(0)$$
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)$$

If the second is smaller, we do not have an absolute minimum because the function is continually decreasing and therefore never reaches an absolute minimum, and not only can we not technically evaluate $f$ at infinity, infinity is excluded from the bounds of your checking. However, luckily, in this case, $f(0)$ is smaller or equal and we can safely say the absolute minimum of $f$ is 0 at $f(0)$

Comment: Note: I assumed you meant $[0,\infty)$ because that is the convention for notating intervals. If your teacher actually meant $[0,\infty]$, however, nothing is changed because we can see that the first is smaller and we cannot evaluate $f(\infty)$